# 2739 Type is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm trying to write an API service in a React app, using Axios and Typescript.

This is my code:

```
interface Service<T> {
  GetAll?: Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
}
interface Example {
  id: Number;
}

const ApiService2 = () => {
  const Example = (): Service<Example> => {
    const GetAll = (): Promise<AxiosResponse<Example[]>> => {
      return axios.get<Example[]>("urlhere");
    };
    return {
      GetAll
    };
  };
};
```

And this is my complete error:

```
Type '() => Promise<AxiosResponse<Example[]>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<Example>>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally  TS2739
```

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? GetAll is a *function that returns a promise*, not a promise.

Comment: last time i checked all crud axios methods return a Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>

Comment: I don't see why you would consider it funny.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand your answer in the first place. I don't have much xp with ts. Now I do understand it, but I'm still not sure how to solve it.

Comment: It depends which part is correct. If the implementation is correct, change the type to reflect what that property actually is. If the type is correct, change the implementation to meet the required interface.

Comment: I think GetAll is a function type despite specifying the return type as <Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you defined you `interface Service` a bit wrong.

The type of `GetAll` should not be `Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>` but a function that returns `Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>` according to your implementation.

So your `Service` interface would become:

```
interface Service<T> {
  GetAll?: () => Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hassan Naqvi, this is what I was looking for.